# *** glibc detected *** ./test: free(): invalid pointer:

Tags: resultset

I am trying to fetch and store ID and Status from Database using statements ID = r->getInt(1) and stat = r->getString(10) where I have declared ID as int and stat as string.
Where first field is an ID containing value 1 and 10th field is status containing value 'A'.
If I try to fetch only ID, my code works fine. Else, when I try to fetch status as well, then while running the code, I am getting below mentioned error:

```
*** glibc detected *** ./test: free(): invalid pointer: 0x000000001c3f5a60 ***
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib64/libc.so.6[0x3d23e71684]
/lib64/libc.so.6(cfree+0x8c)[0x3d23e74ccc]
/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.6(_ZNSsD1Ev+0x3a)[0x3d28a9dc1a]
./test[0x401837]
./test(__gxx_personality_v0+0x310)[0x401120]
/lib64/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf4)[0x3d23e1d8b4]
./test(__gxx_personality_v0+0x89)[0x400e99]
```

Please help.

Adding just the basics of what I am trying to achieve:

```
char loader_session[10];
char sql_query[500];
int ID;
string STATUS;
string CURRENT_CNT_FILE

env = Environment::createEnvironment (Environment::DEFAULT);
conn = env->createConnection( user, passwd, db);
strcpy(loader_session,"TEST");
sprintf(sql_query,"SELECT ID, SESSION_NAME, SRC_SUCCESS_PATH, SRC_CDR_PATH, LOG_FILE, CURRENT_CNT_FILE, LOG_MAX_FILE_CNT, LOG_MAX_FILE_SIZE, PROCEDURE_NAME, STATUS, ERROR_CDR_PATH, LOCK_FILE_PATH FROM TEST_DB WHERE SESSION_NAME = '%s'",loader_session);
Statement* const s = conn->createStatement(sql_query);
s->setPrefetchRowCount(10);
ResultSet* const r = s->executeQuery();
while (r->next())
  {

    ID      =  r->getInt(1);
    STATUS  =  r->getString(10);
    CURRENT_CNT_FILE = r->getString(6);
  }
```

Comment: Please share some of your source code with us. I'm afraid we can't help and point on your mistake without it.

Comment: @MikhailKalashnikov : Please refer the code added.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got a temporary solution for my question. Just by setting MALLOC_CHECK_ to 0, I am not getting the error and my code is running fine. Don't know the side effects of this, but as of now, it's working fine.